# What does CSU in glibc stand for?

Tags: glibc

I was reading an [article](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html) on C startup, and it refers to the function `__libc_csu_init`. Could anyone tell me what CSU stands for?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found a reference to "**C** **s**tart **u**p" in the libc [mailing list](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/2009-12/msg00015.html).
It's far from definitive, but I imagine it's probably correct given what the function does.

Comment: I'll add that `csu/Makefile` contains a comment stating "This directory contains the C startup code (that which calls main)" so it's also corroborated in the repository itself.